# Не удается прочитать данные из файла JSON

Tags: python, json

Есть простой файл JSON

```
{
"foo": "123"
}
```

Попытка прочитать его с помощью кода

```
storage = dict()
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
with open(storage_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    if json_file.read():
        storage = json.load(json_file)
```

При попытке исполнения выбрасывает с ошибкой

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Попытки иначе читать файл с помощью loads к результату тоже не приводят, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Командой

```
if json_file.read():
```

вы читаете *весь* файл, так что *указатель позиции для последующего чтения* перемещен *за конец файла*, а последующая команда *не может уже читать ничего*.

Добавьте после `json_file.read()` команду `json_file.seek(0)` для возвращения указателя на позицию `0` - начало файла:

```
if json_file.read():
    json_file.seek(0)
    storage = json.load(json_file)
```

---

*Примечание:*

Не нужна вам команда `storage = dict()`.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем вы делаете `if json_file.read():` ?

У вас файл оказывается прочитан до конца, и в json.load он будет читаться именно с этой позиции, то есть будет получаться пустая строка.

Либо уберите проверку; либо, если очень хочется проверять, что файл не пуст, - сначала вычитывайте его в строковую переменную, а потом джсон берите из неё, используя `loads` вместо `load`:

```
with open(storage_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    data = json_file.read()
    if data:
        storage = json.loads(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так должно работать:

```
storage = dict()
storage_path = os.path.join(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'storage.data')
with open(storage_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    storage = json.load(json_file)
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в этой проверке `if json_file.read():`.
`json_file` ведет себя так же как и генераторы в Python. To есть, если считать с него все строки один раз, то в следующий раз уже нечего будет считывать.

В этом можно убедиться на примере. Создайте файл "data.json" и попробуйте дважды считать с него данные.

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as json_file:
    a = json_file.read()
    b = json_file.read()
    print('a: ', a)
    print('b: ', b)
```